# How can I play a non-.mp4 videoUrl not using webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am trying to integrate a video player that will play videos with URLs like these ones - https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x8ohlkz?autoplay=1, https://emb.apl268.me/player/video.php?id=282880&s=8e3nb4lt and https://ok.ru/videoembed/6886022842933?autoplay=1

I have tried using a webview but it is affecting the design of my app and I want the player to have the feel and design similar to that of a chewie player. I am using Flutter for the implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! Which platforms are you targeting? Android, iOS, Web? On iOS, I've heard it's possible to play embedded HTML5 videos in a native player, if you add some metadata. If you want to make a custom looking player, you might be able to do so by overlaying a WebView with the original player with custom control UI and relaying the commands via JavaScript, blocking direct access to the original player's inputs.